# EL proceso no puede tener acceso al archivo porque esta siendo utilizado en otro servicio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Hola chicos me pueden apoyar con este error que arroja Visual Studio, lo he intentado ya 2 veces en diferentes proyectos

no se a que se refiere, entre al administrador de tareas y no veo algun Proceso que diiculte  o este ejetuando algo fuera de lo norma

lo estoy haciendo con Store Procedure no la he conectado aun pero aun concetada me lenza el mismo error, me ejcuta muy bien a la primera pero cuando quiero ejecutar el proyecto por segunda vez me lanza ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo en C# que ya lo he revisao y no me genera ningun error

Este es el codigo de la capa Datos

```
namespace Datos
{
    public class SQLControl
    {
        private SqlConnection conectar = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conectar"].ConnectionString);

        public int Pass(string Usuario, string Pass)
        {
            try
            {
                conectar.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("splogin", conectar);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Usuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", Pass);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    return dr.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conectar.Close();
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo del boton registrar para abrir el formulario registrar

```
namespace Inicio
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Registro registro = new Registro();
            this.Hide();
            registro.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Este es mi proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué antivirus tienes? Por otro lado, creo que la ruta que tienes tiene alguna restricción.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en la ruta por defecto que genera Visual Studio que es esta => **C:\Users\DSalgado1989\source\repos**, no utilizo ningún antivirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez el fallo pudiera estar en el código:

```
private void BtnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registro registro = new Registro();
    this.Hide();  //  <<--- Esta línea tal vez sea la causante del error
    registro.ShowDialog();
}
```

Prueba lo siguiente para asegurarnos de cerrar la ventana:

```
private void BtnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Registro registro = new Registro();
    this.Hide();  // Oculta el formulario 
    registro.ShowDialog();
    // Aquí si todo va bien
    this.Close(); // Cerramos el form.
}
```

Después de haberse realizado el registro, se podría poner un condicional; de forma que si todo es correcto pues cierras el *form this.Close();* de otro modo, lo vuelves a mostrar *this.Show();*

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, estuve revisando y el problema estaba donde indicas tu, en vez de cerrar el formulario lo que hace es ocultarlo pero no lo cierra y queda abierto consumiendo memorie, eso lo revisé en el administrador de tareas que aunque lo cerra aún quedaba abierto, modifique el código y le agregue el This.Close y listo así fue como solucione el error. Gracias